# Using DocBlocks - how to indicate that a function returns a value only in some conditions?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, docblocks

I have this function:

```
public function createController()
{
    $valid_controller = class_exists($this->controllerClass)
                    &&  in_array("BaseController", class_parents($this->controllerClass));

    if($valid_controller)
    {
        return new $this->controllerClass($this->urlData["action"]);
    }
    else
    {
        $error = new ErrorController("badurl");
    }
}
```

and I want to create a DocBlock that describe it. This function returns a controller object only if the required controller is valid, and if not, it creates an instace of the `ErrorController` class, but does not return a value. How can I right a proper `@return` tag for this function?

Comment: `@return null|ControllerClass text description or explanation here`

Comment: Why not `null|object`? And please put your answer in... well, an answer, so I can accept it. :)

Comment: Because `object` doesn't have any specific meaning.... you should use an actual interface or object name, that can then be picked up by an IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PHPDocumentor Docs](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/return.html) say to use

```
@return  null|ControllerClass    text description or explanation here
```

Comment: But the `ControllerClass` is a property, and is not constant. So how can i refer to it specifically, since it changes every time?

Comment: What object type is returned? There must be some commonality of inheritance or interface between all your controllers. `BaseController` perhaps?

Comment: In that case `null|BaseController`

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much!